# emulator library that allows to partially emulate old games

Tags: programming, emulation

EDIT: previously I added a lot of examples to this questions. I removed the examples, because the question was voted to be "too broad", so I put more emphasis on the question again.

Question:

Is there an example of a library written in a "modern" multi-purpose language (C++, Python, Java, Go) that loads binaries of an old platform (e.g. 8-bit, 16-bit or 20-bit DOS) and emulates it partially until a given condition, like a break point?

I am looking for a library that allows mixing emulated old binaries with a modern language that doesn't have the same limitations.
I am not looking for an emulator with a scriptable debugger, unless the debugger can be scripted in a common multi-purpose language without restrictions and can be invoked in an automated way.
I am also not looking for software disassembled and ported to a new language.
I am also not looking for porting a modern language to an old system.

Comment: It seems to me that if you know that the game calls to 0x4321 to do something, you could simply replace the routine at 0x4321 with a JMP to your own replacement code, without having to have any special support in the emulator. That's not to say that there aren't other things that might be better done with emulator support; perhaps you can come up with a better example?

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson but I couldn't write that replacement code in python (or any other language other than  x86 assembly), while still being limited by the constraints of a real mode dos program.
I also couldn't use a gamepad on a platform that doesn't support gamepads.

Comment: You certainly do not need to write your code in X86 assembly, aside from the shim that handles converting the calling conventions to whatever you need. I see no reason you couldn't use Python so long as you could get a Python interpreter running under DOS; that would work pretty much the same way calling Python code from C works now. ([Here](http://www.caddit.net/pythond/) is a port of Python 2.4 to DOS. Old, admittedly, but a modern version could probably be ported without too much difficulty if you were willing to strip it down quite a bit.)

Comment: Yes it could be done, but it is not what my question is about. 
I think there is an obvious advantage not being limited by the target platform.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson
I added another possible example, where the keyboard input is replaced by machine learning.
Something that would be hard to achieve on real mode DOS

Comment: Not saying that it is an easy way, but MAME takes care of this. Emulates a lot of platforms, is open source and you can tweak and recompile the platforms you like to change.

Comment: DOSBox should handle most DOS games.

Comment: @UncleBod  As mentioned in point 1), I am not looking for an emulator alone. If you can give an example of how MAME is used as a library you can make this an answer.

Comment: @RichF As mentioned in point 1), I am not looking for an emulator alone. If you can give an example of how DOSBox is used as a library you can make this an answer.

Comment: I'm also failing to see the suitability of MAME/DOSBox here given the scope of changes it sounds like Helena has in mind. Suppose she wanted to add a particle effect when Mario jumps — if you're writing Mario-specific code and tapped in to the full state of the hardware you know which sprite he is so you have his location, you can spot entry into the jump routine, so throw on some particles. You couldn't do that on real hardware due to sprite limits and constrained processing resources. So you couldn't easily patch it into an emulator without being able to do an end-run around the emulation.

Comment: What you are describing is not the function of a library IMHO. You are asking for an emulator (library or not) with an scriptable debugger, OR the integration of a debugger and a decompiler/patcher (IDA + HexRays here) But you specifically said no disassembly, so... 
I believe you can use MAME source code as a library to emulate and patch the game, but it will be far better if you just add those capabilities to the existing debugger (but this is no easy task, i think).

Comment: I don't know how to improve this question. I think the question was very concise from the beginning. "Is there an example library that allows for partial emulation and then returns the control flow to the host language."  
I added a lot of examples, how I was planning to use it, because people didn't understand why I  wanted and kept telling me that it is not useful.
Now the question is on-hold as 'too broad', presumably because I have too many examples. 
Should I remove all the examples again?

Comment: The question is too broad because you appear not to understand the technical details of what you want to do. As I said in my answer, pick a very specific instance (a particular game, and specific changes you want to make) and actually implement those changes (with or without using the ideas you express here), and you will almost certainly come to understand the problems with your question and why your proposed solution is "doing it the hard way."

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson I'd prefer if you keep the critique at the question and not direct it at the person. I can change the question, but I cannot fix change whether you think I am understanding the technical details or not.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Picking one specific game or change defeats the purpose, because my question is not "How do I do change X in game Y" but my question is "Is there any libraries that allow partial emulation".
You continue to insist that this is not what I want, but this is exactly what I want.

Comment: To me, it sounds like you are looking exactly for a emulator with a scriptable debugger, plus some extra features like the ability to take the various graphical layers & sound channels and do post-processing on them to generate the final image/sound. With the scriptable debugger, you can override or augment functions, allowing you to add whatever logic you wish (read/write memory locations, read/write io registers, modify your post-processing data, etc.) without impacting the original code (no need to worry about cycles, no need to worry about ROM space). [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] Of course, in order to know which memory locations to override/augment/read/write, you absolutely need to disassemble the game and know its inner workings - there's no way around that. But other than that, there're no limits to what such a emulator could allow you to do - anything that you can't do within the limits of the original hardware, could instead be done in the post-processing stage (add sounds, add graphic effects, etc). E.g. you can even ignore the original image output and generate the graphics yourself with enough work (and that's a huge amount of work, to be clear) [cont]

Comment: [cont.] All that said, while I know that some emulators with rerecording support have some of the above functionality scriptable by lua (e.g. show some on-screen UI, most likely breakpoint callbacks), they probably don't have all the features to allow you to do full-scale post-processing over the graphical/sound output of the game as previously described - but I imagine it wouldn't be too hard to add this to them (the emulators are open-source, and have much of what you need already).

Comment: @secondperson You're right that this could be done and about how to do it, but the question is, why would you go to all that extra work rather than just changing the program, given that you've already disassembled and studied it in detail? (Obviously you may also, depending on the specific problem, need to add I/O devices to the emulator or change the existing ones, but that doesn't require adding this whole debugger capability in what is probably timing-critical code in the emulator.)

Comment: [Libretro](https://www.libretro.com/) might fit the bill; you’d be writing a frontend, which would drive whichever backend core is appropriate. Cores are given games to run (*e.g.* a ROM image), and then told when to update the game state (one frame at a time), and given the inputs (button presses etc.).

Comment: Removing the examples doesn't fix the fact that the question is too broad; it's still the same question, and still suffering from the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): you're asking how to implement an overly complex solution to the particular problems you're interested in. I've added an example to the end of [my answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12176/7208) that shows one instance where there's a much simpler solution than what you're trying to propose; this example is typical of any change you want to make to a game or other software.

Comment: @secondperson You are right, the line between what I am looking for and a scriptable debugger is very thing. I'd go for that as well as an answer, as long as the debugger is scriptable in a multipurpose language (as opposed to a limited language specific to the debugger) and can be invoked without needing GUI interaction.

Comment: @secondperson I like your suggestion of using some kind of post processing to not have to deal with cycle issues. 
The way I imagined it was to analyze the cycle time of a subroutine I am replacing and then telling the emulator to wait N cycles before continuing. 
Of course you are right, that this needs heavy reverse engineering.

Comment: MAME can be scripted in Lua; this may not exactly fit your requirements, but here's an example of what MAME + Lua can do: https://dammit.typepad.com/blog/2010/09/street-fighter-alpha-series-hitboxes.html

Answer (score 2):

**Your question seems to have an inherent contradiction in it.** You appear to be saying that you don't want to "[d]isassemble the original game and rewrite the...routines," but all the examples you give (intercept a call to a memory location, intercept a software interrupt when a register has a specific value) are ones that would require the kind of knowledge of the code you get only through disassembly (or access to source code) and, once you have that, the easiest way to implement changes is usually just to change the code directly.

I doubt you'll find an emulator that provides that kind of "intercept" facility because that capability is already easily available in the machine itself: just change the code at a memory location or an interrupt handler to do what you want. (This is in fact often exactly how debuggers do this.)

Note that this technique does not limit your capabilities in any way: **you can use it to call new code in any language runnining within the emulated machine** or, by using the I/O facilities provided by the emulator, communicate with code running outside the emulated machine. (Your new routine needs to provide the API provided by the original routine, but it can of course marshal arguments for the substitute routine as necessary, e.g., push information in registers on to the stack to call compiled C code or call into a Python interpreter, and when that returns, unmarshal the results back into registers to return to the game code.)

Let's look at your examples:

1. If the subroutine at 0x1234 returns a key code whose value is used for movement (say, one of the two arrow keys) and you wish to use a gamepad, replace the routine with one that calls the emulator's I/O routines for gamepad input and translates the left/right presses on the gamepad to the appropriate key codes.
2. If you have a machine learning model running in another process outside the emulator, attach the communications channel between these two processes as an I/O device into the emulator and, in your substitute routine(s), write information out to that I/O device to send it to the other process, reading from that I/O device to get whatever information the other process wants to send back.
3. To replace only some of the code for a software interrupt handler (or anything else, for that matter), copy that routine elsewhere and replace it with your own code that calls your new routine if AH = 0x3F or calls the original code otherwise.
4. Changing the display of a side-scroller to have a bigger screen area can't be done by just replacing a few routines. As [Bruce Abbott points out](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12180/7208), this typically involves substantial changes to the game code itself because it won't be drawing more than the screen area and a little bit around it on a continuous basis, as you can see in the examples given at 32:32 and later in Michael Steil's [The Ultimate Game Boy Talk](https://youtu.be/HyzD8pNlpwI?t=1755). (The link I give you starts at 29:15; to understand the difficulties with what you're proposing you very much need to understand everything in the Pixel Processing Unit section of that video.)
5. Loading more data than fits into the memory/address space limitations of the original hardware has similar deep issues: the game doesn't know how to access the additional memory you wish to add, and you need to change the game itself to understand that the additional memory is there and how to access it. There's no way an emulator can do this for you.
6. Speeding up parts of the program to make it do more (e.g., allow more players in a multiplayer game) is an even deeper problem yet: remember that most action game code outside of modern platforms has assumptions about machine timing deeply embedded throughout the entire program: this is why older IBM PC clones used to include a "turbo" button to slow the machine down to original IBM PC speed, and why emulators take very great care not to run instructions faster or slower than the original hardware they're emulating.

It's certainly possible to write a "scriptable debugger" (as [flavio aptly terms it](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/225/flavio)) integrated into an emulator, but I doubt anybody would see much point, since once you've decided to change something beyond the API provided by the hardware I/O devices in the system it's easier and more reliable just to change the code you're running.

Because you're asking here about a particular implementation of a solution to a seemingly vague and general problem that you don't describe in detail, on reflection I think this question should probably be closed as too broad. I'd suggest you create a new question stating exactly what game you're trying to modify and describing specifically what you want to change about it, and let others suggest the best way of implementing that change. Once you have a few questions like this, you may be able to start asking about more general techniques for dealing with that type of problem. (For things like this, it's almost invariably better to generalize from specific solved cases, rather than try to generalize before anybody's seen specific problems and solutions.)

#### An Example Change

Your question appears to be an example of an ["XY problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): you're asking "how can I use X to do Y" when the easiest solution is "don't use X, use something else." Here I provide a small example that I hope will help clarify this.

Let's say a game uses the arrow keys to move left and right because when it was originally designed the computer it ran on didn't have a gamepad. A gamepad was later made available on that system (as an expansion card or added to a later version of the computer) and the emulator emulates this.

You've disassembled and analyzed the game to the degree that you know it calls a routine at `$3210` to check for input, and expects `0`, `1` or `2` to be returned in the `A` register indicating nothing, left or right being held down at that moment. The routine itself writes and reads I/O ports to scan the keyboard.

Your suggestion for doing this seems to be to add code to the emulator that keeps a list of addresses at which it should stop emulation, and call host code that is dynamically linked in in some way. That code then needs to use internal APIs (if they even exist) to interface with the emulator's code that handles device input and to get the gamepad status, load the emulated machine's `A` register with the appropriate `0`/`1`/`2` result, and somehow externally reset the machine's state to return from that call to `$3210`. This is quite tricky; perhaps it could fake an instruction load of `RET` instead of letting the emulator load whatever instruction the PC currently points to? And keep in mind that you may have to maintain timing dependencies, too, by delaying for however long the original routine would have taken.

That's the hard way of doing it. The easy way is simply to replace the routine at that location with one that reads different I/O ports supplied by the emulator to read the gamepad instead of the keyboard. This requires no changes to the emulator at all, no access to the emulator's internal APIs or internal code, and is much less code and much less complex code overall. Even if the emulator doesn't offer the emulated device you need, it's far easier to add just the emulation for that device than to add what's essentially a debugger and go grovelling around in the internals of the emulator's code. Note that the emulator side of the device can do anything it wants on the host machine, even starting and communicating with other processes or the like.

You're not likely to find emulators that already support your solution because why would the developers of an emulator go to all the work of adding this pseudo-debugger and internal APIs and the like when there's a much simpler solution available?

If it's really important that an unpatched binary be loaded, you might tweak the emulator to load and apply patches after the original binary is loaded, but before emulation starts.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. As mentioned, I do not want to extend the game by writing new machine code for the old platform.
I have been asking for an approach that allows using a modern programming language that can make full use of the host system. 

Using IO to communicate with a separate thread is an interesting idea, but I would have to write machine code to communicate the game information to the outside.

But I am taking your feedback that it is unclear what I want, so I added more examples and what I am thinking of doing with this library.

Comment: @Helena The technique I provided does _exactly_ allow you to use a modern programming language and full use of the host system; please re-read my answer carefully with this in mind. I've boldfaced a couple of important points in my question. It's true that you still have to use a tiny amount of assembler code, but the level of understanding you need to have of the original game's code is such that it will be trivial to write this minimal amount of assembler to interface with your modifications written in another langauge such as C or Python, whether running within the emulator or outside it.

Comment: @Helena I've also added points 4, 5 and 6 to address your new examples; from those new examples you give it's pretty clear at this point you don't understand very well the problem you're trying to solve, and therefore you don't understand why the solution you're proposing doesn't make sense. What you want to do is a lot more complex than you think it is. This is why I suggest you pick a specific game and a specific modification you'd like to make to it and actually try to implement that: this will give you the understanding of the problem that you're currently missing.

Answer (score 2):

> I am imagining to combine the best of both worlds by having a
>   emulation library that allows me to do everything an emulator does,
>   but also gives me the opportunity to only emulate parts of the code
>   (e.g. run a subroutine until it returns), or have callbacks that give
>   the control back to the language I am calling it from.

This is what emulators already do, since at some point they have to translate virtual machine operations into real OS calls and operations that access the actual hardware. Many emulators have a built-in debugger with breakpoints that can be set at code locations or when certain operations occur, which could be a good place to add your own callback hooks.

However this doesn't mean you can just tap into the emulated code at any point and jam stuff into it expecting it to work. Most games for home computers such as Amstrad CPC etc. were written in assembly language (or even raw machine code) without the use of standard libraries or APIs other than perhaps file and keyboard I/O. They often used tricks such as self-modifying code to squeeze more out of the limited memory and processing power. And they were intimately tied to the hardware, wringing the most out of it with whatever worked (sometimes using undocumented 'features' that have taken emulator writers years to reproduce accurately).

Once you start playing with the code all bets are off, unless you know exactly what it is doing and how it can be safely modified. Even something as 'simple' as increasing the number of characters or making the screen bigger is likely to break the code that uses that data. Graphics may be stored in a non-standard format which is specific to the particular game, with a structure that needs to be understood and preserved.

What this means is that before you can consider using emulated code as a 'library', you need to understand what its requirements and dependencies are. Making significant enhancements such as larger screen size or more objects may require extensive modifications which increase the chances of creating bugs.

> is there any examples of games that are extensions of
>   old games that use a hybrid approach of emulating code of the original
>   platform and running code on the emulating host platform.

Closest I can think of is the [SPEC256](http://www.emulatronia.com/emusdaqui/spec256/comofunciona-eng.htm), which is a ZX Spectrum emulator enhanced to provide 256 color graphics. To handle the extra memory required it runs a '64 bit Z80' in parallel with the normal 8 bit CPU emulation. The developers have created tools for extracting monochrome graphics from a game and integrating the 256 color equivalents. However they haven't released the tools or any source code, and I'm betting that each game needs a lot of custom patches to get the 256 color graphics working properly.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up SPEC256, this looks indeed a partial match to what I am looking for, as it goes beyond the limitations of the original platform.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote a Spec256-alike a while ago, and avoiding custom code is almost impossible. I targetted the game Dan Dare, and one thing it does is it reverses its sprites using a 256 byte lookup table. So you're not really going to succeed with a parallel 64-bit Z80 alone. I had to trap the sprite flipping routine and implement that in native code.

Comment: See the The Day of the Tentacle remake post-mortem here: https://youtu.be/HqWrdIf69M8 it emulates the DOS version and then snoops it's memory to generate the improved graphics.